# How to match two string arrays - 3 conditions?

Tags: arrays, go, matching

I have a logical question here.  I need to print a string in the format "user@email.com group@email.com" for each user whose business title and manager fit the business title, department and manager in the group CSV. If there's more than one matching group the string should be printed as above but with another group. What would be the best approach here? Create arrays from both CSV files then do an if in the loop?

**Example**

GroupCSV:

```
Group,Job title,Department,Manager (email address)
somesalesgroup@dundermifflin.com,Senior Sales Manager,Sales,michael.scott@dundermifflin.com
anothersalesgroup@dundermifflin.com,Senior Sales Manager,Sales,michael.scott@dundermifflin.com
```

UserCSV:

```
First name,Last name,Location,Start date,Job title,Department,Manager (email address)
Jim,Halpert,Scranton,7/1/2021,Senior Sales Manager,Sales,michael.scott@dundermifflin.com
Dwight,Schrute,Scranton,7/1/2021,Assistant to the Regional Manager,Sales,michael.scott@dundermifflin.com
```

I would like to have an output like:

```
[jim.halpert@dundermifflin@takeaway.com somesalesgroup@dundermifflin.com]
[jim.halpert@dundermifflin@takeaway.com anothersalesgroup@dundermifflin.com]
```

**At the moment I've got this**

```
var match [][]string
    for _, u := range userRows {
        for _, g := range groupRows {
            if u[0] == g[0] {
                match = append(match, string{g, u})
            }
        }
    }
```

But I'm not sure what may be wrong here (string{g, u})

Comment: Well, `string{g, u}` is clearly invalid code. But I don't know what you should do instead, because I don't know your intention. What type are `g` and `u`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this way:

```
var match [][]string
    for _, u := range userRows {
        for _, g := range groupRows {
            if u[6] == g[1] && u[2] == g[0] {
                match = append(match, []string{u[5], g[2]})
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

The way I can think of is to convert GroupCSV into a map, and then read UserCSV to match the map.
If the process of reading the CSV file is a "for", there are two "for" in total.